# Listen for MediaEnded event in another window

Tags: c#, wpf, events, window, mediaelement

I'm making a simple C# WPF video player app.

I have 2 Windows: The MainWindow (Parent window) contains the MediaElement to display the video.  The PlaylistWindow (Child window) is the window that contains a ListBox that displays all the .avi files in the appRoot path.

Currently, when I double-click on a ListBox item, it plays that video in MainWindow.  I would like to have an auto-play feature so the next item in the list is automatically played when the current video ends.

I would like PlaylistWindow to listen for the MediaEnded event triggered by the MediaElement in MainWindow so I can perform some action on the ListBox in PlaylistWindow.

How can I subscribe to the MediaEnded event from PlaylistWindow?

Edit to Add:
I ended up using a different approach as shown below.
I don't think this is the best way to do it, but it works for me.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    PlaylistWindow PLWindow = new PlaylistWindow();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PLWindow.Owner = this;
        PLWindow.Show();
    }

    private void videoWindow_Ended(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PLWindow.playNext();
    }
}

public partial class PlaylistWindow : Window
{
    public void playNext()
    {
        if (playListBox.SelectedIndex < playListBox.Items.Count - 1)
        {
            playListBox.SelectedIndex = playListBox.SelectedIndex + 1;
        }
        else { playListBox.SelectedIndex = 0; }

        (Owner as MainWindow).playVideo(playListBox.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

I'm still open to learning about how to listen for the MediaEnded event in PlaylistWindow if a code sample can be posted.

Answer (score 1):

Raise custom .net event from Main window(this custom event will be raised by Media ended event) and subscribe it in Playlist window, in the event handler of this event return the file name of next .avi file